# Am I able to wire a 3-Prong dryer outlet with 8/3 Romex?

Tags: electrical, dryer, appliances

I see similar questions but maybe not as specific....

I am moving my laundry location. As we are intending a remodel eventually I just used some 8/3 romex I had left over to junction with the existing 10/3 cable to the dryer. They had this hooked to a 3-prong outlet. It wasn't until I was preparing the new 3-prong outlet that I realized my 8/3 is meant for a 4-prong. Can I still wire the 3-prong with the 8/3 romex?

Comment: Is there a grounding wire in all the NM cable involved in this circuit?  Can you post a photo of the box where the 10/3 transitions to the new 8/3?

Answer (score 5):

You could. **But don't!**

Instead, replace the 3-wire outlet with a 4-wire outlet. It is much safer. There are no downsides. You will have to replace the dryer cord/plug with a 4-wire cord/plug, and remove the jumper connecting ground and neutral on the dryer (typically a green wire going from the neutral connection to some bare metal spot on the dryer).

You would have to do the same thing if it was a 10/3 as well. That is, assuming your 10/3 is (like the 8/3) 3 regular wires (typically black/red/white) + a ground wire.

If your 10/3 does **not** have a ground wire, ask for more help.

Answer (score 5):

3-prong outlets aren't "your dryer outlet".  3-prong outlets are an obsolete and dangerous form of outlet that's been outlawed since 1990, but has been grandfathered in old installations.  Because of this grandfathering, and the fact that the home stores sell them *as unit replacements for broken sockets*, people just keep installing them.

Stop.

You must convert this setup to a 4-prong outlet.  It's not optional, it's a Code requirement.

You must also change the dryer cord to a 4-prong cord.  Google the dryer instructions and they will tell you to remove a bonding strap connecting neutral to the dryer's   chassis/ground, and then wire up the 4-wire ground wire to chassis, and the other 3 wires just as before.  (with the bonding strap removed!)